# Perl - convert string to datetime

Tags: perl, datetime, data-conversion

I'm working on a script that fetches data from a log file. The log file contains date string in a particular format:

```
20190626-102908.616319
```

Once it's parsed through my code, I want the date to be in another format:

```
2019-06-26-10:29:08
```

I've used `DateTime::Format::Strptime` and that works perfectly.

BUT, the requirement is to use another way as the system the script will be used on does not allow installing new modules (yeah, I cannot install additional Perl modules).

The only thing I can work with would be `Date::Parse` or `Date::Format`, but I cannot make it cooperate.

With `Date::Parse`:

```
my $time2 = str2time($chunks[0]);
```

I only get empty output.

Calling `Date::Format`:

```
my $time2 = time2str("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S\n", $chunks[0]);
```

gives just `1970-01-01-00:00:00`.

Could anyone point me into right direction here?

Comment: *"..used on does not allow installing new modules.."* Why not? It allows you to write a script, so why can it not allow you to write (i.e. download) a module?

Comment: @HåkonHægland it's a very closed system unfortunately...

Comment: So you cannot download anything on your system?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, no, unfortunately not. I know it's counterproductive, but that's the requirement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given 20190626-102908.616319 as the content of $string

```
my ($date,$time) = split /-/, $string; # Separate time from date
$time = int $time; # Drop decimal parts of a second
my @date = $date =~ /([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/; # Split date into year month day
my @time = $time =~ /([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/; # Split time into hour month second
my $formatted_date = join('-', @date) . '-' . join(':', @time); # Put it all back together
```

Comment: As others have said, what version of Perl are you using and why can't you use standard modules?

Comment: as I've explained, there is a limitation for the system to install modules/packages, it has to be as it is from this perspective. I know it's counterproductive, but I'm not calling the shots...

Answer (score 2):

[`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) is a module that has been in core since v5.10.0 and has comparable date parsing / formatting APIs:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use feature qw(say);
use Time::Piece; 

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("20190626-102908.616319","%Y%m%d-%H%M%S");
say $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S");
# 2019-06-26-10:29:08
```

Comment: Note that Time::Piece only supports down to the second resolution, so you'll get a warning about leftover microseconds in your input. You could remove it with [`substr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) if it bothers you.

Comment: that might work and is a good solution too, but I cannot use this module as well.. Thanks!

Comment: @Bart Are you using a Perl that is older than 5.8?

Comment: that's not a problem, just that the system I'm writing the script for is closed for installation of packages/modules. in real world, your solution would work and I've tried it locally as well.

Comment: @Bart I think you misunderstand, this module _comes with_  Perl by default. There is no additional installation needed.

Comment: ah, that's `v5.10.1`, so in theory should work, but doesn't on the system: `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at - line 1.`

Comment: @Bart That means you do not have a complete Perl installation. If this is a Redhat system, make sure `perl-core` is installed, or complain to whoever is supposed to be providing Perl.

Comment: Actually, Time::Piece was added to Perl 5.10.0 (not 5.8.0). And I bet Bart's problem is that he's using a system with Red Hat's crippled Perl installation. See [A Cautionary Tale](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/) for details.

Comment: @DaveCross Good catch, I'll edit to include that. My reference was an article that was incorrect, I should have used `corelist` instead :|